# I want to use sed or awk to append multiple lines that meet a criteria, after a line containing a pattern is found

Tags: awk, sed

I have this text:

```
Sample: 1
Description: THIS SAMPLE CONTAINS DATA FROM WITH THE FOLLOWING CRITERIA
BLAH BLAH BLAH
BLAH BLAH BLAH.   
random label:
```

how would I concatenate certain lines in the file so that it looks like this:

```
Sample: 1
Description: THIS SAMPLE CONTAINS DATA MEETING THE FOLLOWING CRITERIA BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH.
random label:
```

The only certainty, is that
every line immediately following "Description", that starts with, and contains all uppercase letters, will be concatenated to the line containing "Description".

Random label, means the label will be one of 60 labels.

Comment: What have you done to try to solve this.  We are here to help you with your code.

Comment: If you need an answer please explain why `BLAH BLAH BLAH.` that does not *contain all uppercase letters* is still concatenated. Do you mean you want to concat all subsequent lines with letters but no lowercase letters? What is the line is numeric, say `12.35`?

Comment: The BLAH BLAH BLAH  are all uppercase words. Any line that contains lowercase is not to be concatenated. no numerics are contained. The specs would then be, once you find the label "Description:", concatenate all following line that start with an uppercase character. Keep on doing this until you come to a line that does not start with an uppercase character.

Comment: Ok, try `sed -E ':a;/^Description:/{N;/\n[^[:lower:]]*[[:lower:]]/!s/\n/ /; ta}' file > newfile`

Comment: your solution is not including the line beginning with Description. It does concatenate all the other lines with caps though. A good start :)

Comment: See https://ideone.com/HFiTuy - all the lines are there

Comment: Well, does `sed -i '/^Description:/{:a;N;/\n[^[:lower:]]*[[:lower:]]/!s/\n/ /;ta;P;D}' file` work?

Comment: There might be a better way to approach this but you'd have to show us more than just 1 input record in your sample input/output to know for sure.

Comment: The reason the code wasn't working is because my environment uses crlf or \r\n This works fine: sed -E ':a;/^Description:/{N;/\n[^[:lower:]]*[[:lower:]]/!s/\r\n/ /; ta}'

Comment: I can’t give you any points since your answer, is in your comment. If you submit an answer, I will gladly give you points.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^Description/{:a;N;/\n[[:upper:]]/s/\n/ /;ta;P;D}' file
```

Gather up lines beginning with an uppercase letter starting from the line beginning `Description`

If you want only lines not containing lowercase letters, use:

```
sed '/^Description/{:a;N;/\n.*[[:lower:]]/!s/\n/ /;ta;P;D}' file
```